# Cloud sync strategy

Tags: android, google-app-engine, caching, cloud, backend

Firstly: This will be implemented for Android using Google App Engine & Google Cloud SQL/Datastore but it's more the over arching strategy that I'm a bit confused about.

I'm creating an Android app that will record an activity. I'd then like to be able to sync this activity to the cloud and have the activities viewable/editable on any other devices registered to the user. The specifics of authentication, device registration and all that I can work out, it's more so the sync strategy that I'm having trouble with.

**Requirements will be:**

1. Activity is recorded on a users device
2. Activity is stored in cloud after being recorded
3. Devices should check the cloud for an updated list of activities and maintain a local 'cache' of activities (will be a SQLite database) to display to the user.

These are my initial thoughts on how I'll implement this:

**Scenario: Recording activity**

1. Record Activity on Device
2. Once Recorded upload data to cloud
3. Force sync with cloud to update local cache
4. Show user locally cached activities (which will include the recently added one because of the previous sync step).

**Scenario: Updating activity**

1. User selects cached activity
2. Makes changes
3. Uploads change to cloud (and marks it as modified somehow? not sure how this will work)
4. Force sync with cloud to update local cache
5. Show user locally cached activities (which will include updated content of the activity because of the previous sync step).

**Problem: Sync local cache with cloud data**

I'm not exactly sure how to implement the sync (i.e. steps 3 & 4 of the previous scenarios respectively). I don't want to discard the local cache and re-download everything to ensure the latest data as that seems terribly in-efficient. Preferably I'd like to just download activities that aren't in the cache and update activities that are in the cache but have been changed since the last sync.

Are there any best practices / well known sync patterns (that are easyish to understand) that will help me achieve this?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2):

You will also need to consider connection loss/retries, battery/power efficiency, and possibly apply custom sync algorithms.

Android already has an excellent pattern/API to address these issues and handle background sync with your back-end server in an efficient way.

Follow [the official android guide for sync adapter API pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) , you do not have to implement content provider or authenticator if you do not need them, just implement stubs for them.

Here are couple of example projects to help you through...

- Basic example, available at above [link called BasicSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/BasicSyncAdapter.zip)
- Look at [Google iosched app](https://github.com/google/iosched) for more advanced usage, and best practices including the usage of GCM for triggering your sync, among others.